# C++ | Boundary Condition For Graphic

Tags: c++

My C++ knowledge is pretty new but I've been coding in java for the past 2 years. I decided I'd take a leap of faith and learn a new language. Anyway, I've been following this amazing SFML tutorial online and I realized that it was a little too easy for my tastes so I wanted to create a Boundary for These ball objects we are coding so they can bounce around in the provided window. To my surprise, my Algorithm failed me. I'm going to show a Reduced version of the guys online tutorial for only the Red Circle Object.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Variables Demo");

  sf::CircleShape circleRed(10);//Radius to 10

  circleRed.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 0, 0));//Color to Red

  float x = true;
  float y = true;

  float xRed = 100;
  float yRed = 100;

  circleRed.setPosition(xRed, yRed);

  while (window.isOpen())
  {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        window.close();
    }
    window.clear();

   //x and yRed are modified here.
    if (xRed >= 589 || xRed <= 9)
    x = !x;

    if (x = true)
        xRed = xRed + .3;
    else 
        xRed = xRed - .3;

    if (yRed >= 789 || yRed <= 9)
        y = !y;

    if (y = true)
      yRed = yRed + .3;
    else yRed = yRed - .3;

    circleRed.setPosition(xRed, yRed);

    window.draw(circleRed);

    window.display();

  }//This is the end of the "while" loop

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x` and `y` should be of `bool`ean type, not `float`, and the `if` conditions should use the comparison operators instead of `=`, e.g. `if (x == true)` which is the same as `if (x)`.

Comment: String me = "FacePalm";

Comment: Thanks I didnt realize that my if statement wasnt equal checking, instead it was throwing a warning

Comment: It isn't just throwing a warning, it is modifying the variable on the left!